# XMLTABLE in oracle how to handle null columns'

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype, xmltable

Hi,
I need to extract data from one of the tables which have one XML column.
For some of the records, the XML column is not having any data. And when I am using the below query I am getting error.

We need to run this query, whether the table has data or not in the XML column.

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTAB_1 (A_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
                   , ID VARCHAR2(50) 
                   , A_DATE DATE 
                   , O_ID NUMBER 
                   , XML_KEY CLOB);


INSERT INTO  XMLTAB_1 (A_ID, ID, A_DATE ,O_ID)
VALUES (11,'SA-AND-11-12345',sysdate,null);
INSERT INTO  XMLTAB_1 (A_ID, ID, A_DATE ,O_ID,XML_KEY )
VALUES (12,'SA-AND-12-12345',sysdate,null,'<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="UTF-16" standalone="n'"?><al><al_cd><comments><columns><time>2020-07-07 08:45:08 </time><auth>xzy</auth><a_status>new</a_status><assgn>katy</assgn><text>new record </text></columns><columns><time>2020-07-07 09:45:08 </time><auth>abcd</auth><a_status>in progress</a_status><assgn>katy_1</assgn><text>work in progress </text></columns></comments></al_cd></al>');
COMMIT;
```

```
SELECT A_ID
       , ID
       , A_DATE
       , O_ID
       , TO_DATE(C_time,'YYYY_MM_DD HH24:MI:SS') ctime
       , auth
       , status
       , assgn 
       , cmmnt  
       , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A_ID ORDER BY TO_DATE(C_time,'YYYY_MM_DD HH24:MI:SS') DESC) rnk
FROM XMLTAB_1 a
     , XMLTABLE('al/al_cd/comments/columns'
           PASSING XMLTYPE(a.XML_KEY) COLUMNS
                c_time   VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'time'
                , auth   VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'auth'
                , status VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'a_status'
                , assgn  VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'assgn'
                , cmmnt  VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'text') xt
```

I am getting error for record a_id as 11 fo 12 it's working fine.

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: Numeric or value error ORA:-06512 :at
> "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272

Could anyone please let me know how to achieve this and remove the error from the code.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the DDL of the tables... Maybe it will help...

Comment: CREATE TABLE XMLTAB_1
(A_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
,ID VARCHAR2(50)
,A_DATE DATE
,O_ID NUMBER
XML_KEY CLOB
......); Apart from these columns, there are lots of other columns as well. Total Columns are 97 and it's not possible to give details of all other columns, so providing details of only selected columns that we re using in our select statement.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you had a minimal reproducible test case: the ddl of a table (with  only the relevant columns),the dml for a couple of rows of data and then the sql that throws this error. That way, if any of the members of SO want to reproduce your example, they only need to run your scripts to see your error. 
Do not put those in comments but edit your question.

Comment: As @KoenLostrie wrote you should provide us the example that throws this error because this is the best what I can do without data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9c0343e51b519163a7dfc409e31e693 And you cansee that all works...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't just want to filter out the rows with null values, completely, in a `where` clause, you could use a case expression within the `passing` clause:

```
...
XMLTABLE('al/al_cd/comments/columns'
   PASSING CASE WHEN a.XML_KEY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE XMLTYPE(a.XML_KEY) END
   COLUMNS c_time VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'time',
...
```

The XPath looks odd, and possibly should be '/al/al_cd/comments/columns', though it works with either.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0acbab8f7212c1d7bc8b10ff723635b2) building on @vBoka's. I've changed the old-style cross join to an outer apply to make the row with the null value show up, which requires Oracle 12c+.

If you're on an earlier version when you can use an outer join with an always-true condition, which is a bit of a hack. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=99637df66149f641fb181f285b9c4c20); or [with your sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de756d3bf3406f54425c121fbc504735), which gives:

```
A_ID | ID              | A_DATE    | O_ID | CTIME     | AUTH | STATUS      | ASSGN  | CMMNT             | RNK
---: | :-------------- | :-------- | ---: | :-------- | :--- | :---------- | :----- | :---------------- | --:
  11 | SA-AND-11-12345 | 15-JUL-20 | null | null      | null | null        | null   | null              |   1
  12 | SA-AND-12-12345 | 15-JUL-20 | null | 07-JUL-20 | abcd | in progress | katy_1 | work in progress  |   1
  12 | SA-AND-12-12345 | 15-JUL-20 | null | 07-JUL-20 | xzy  | new         | katy   | new record        |   2
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex for the solution. But mine is 11c and the Outer apply is not working in it.

Comment: @user8592197 - you want to see the row with null XML in the output though, right?

Comment: yes Alex. I achieved it using differrent blocks but the select query is taking lots of time to get the output. My table is having million of records.

Comment: It will take a while to convert all of the XML and then extract all the values, yes. Not sure what you mean about blocks; maybe a union of null and not-null CLOB column values? If so the case approach might be faster but not sure there would be a lot of difference.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexPoole! Both for the "CASE WHEN" solution and also for the OUTER APPLY approach on db<>fiddle :)